# Representation of a (closed) subspace of Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

What would be the most intuitive way to perceive a closed subspace of Hilbert space. We know that any subspace of a finite-dimensional Hilbert space is closed.

Could we use the simplest analogy with $\Bbb{R}^2$, which Hilbert space, and say that every line which passes through the center of our space is closed subspace?

Comment: I don't think there's an intuitive way to perceive non-closed subspaces of Hilbert (or normed) spaces. That's because the phenomenon occures in infinite dimension, which is far from our intuition. The line analogy is too simple. Lines (as in 1 dimensional subspaces) are closed in any normed vector space, finite dimensional or not. In fact for a linear subspace to be non-closed both the space and the subspace have to have infinite dimension. Obviously this is necessary but not a sufficient condition.

Comment: What Hilbert spaces are you familiar with? Continuous functions or polynomials are non-closed subspaces of $L^2([0,1])$. On the other hand, functions with zero average are a closed subspace. Closed subspaces are pretty much analogous to lines and planes through the origin in 3D space, non-closed ones are not, they are *dense* in some such closed subspace. If we drop the requirement that spaces are over reals than rationals are such a dense non-closed subspace of reals.

Comment: In a Hilbert space, a subset $S$ is a closed subspace if and only if $S=\{s\mid\forall x\in X:\langle s,x\rangle=0\}$ for some subset $X$.